# Not able to get prices from stripe using stripe prices api

Tags: asp.net-mvc, api, stripe-payments, http-status-code-500

I am trying to get prices from stripe in an asp.net mvc project using stripe api call. the codes works locally and gets all the prices from stripe but when I run the code in production server it shows and error.
I am using this code

```
StripeConfiguration.ApiKey = "my-key";
            var options = new PriceListOptions { Limit = 10,Active=true };
            options.AddExpand("data.product");
            var service = new PriceService();
            StripeList<Price> prices = service.List(options);

            return View(prices);
```

The error it shows online is

> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 34.241.54.72:80

Answer (score 0):

You should run the [reachability tool](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-reachability) to ensure your server is able to communicate with Stripe's servers. If not, you need to figure out what part of your network configuration is preventing the connections and add appropriate rules for Stripe published [domains and IP addresses](https://stripe.com/docs/ips).

If this is only intermittent, you can try enabling [automatic retries](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-dotnet#automatic-retries) to see if the issue gets better.

```
StripeConfiguration.MaxNetworkRetries = 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the hosting provider (IONOS) and was solved after adding proxy in the web.config file.

```
<system.net>
  <defaultProxy>
     <proxy  proxyaddress="http://winproxy.server.lan:3128" bypassonlocal="true"/>  
  </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```